# Restart a file on change python watchdog

Tags: python, application-restart, python-watchdog

I would like to implement an automatic restart option in my script(script will restart itself on any change, like deletion or creation of the file in a directory). I need it to be cross-platform, and I am able to get events on file changes using watchdog. My questions is, how can I properly restart file itself after getting event from watchdog? Using os.exec* family didn't help, so I think using subprocess would fix the issue: I need to replace current process with a new launched one. Any ideas?

Here's the code I am launching:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

print('STARTED THE SCRIPT')

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        # i need to restart the script itself here.
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so I'll give you some ideas to produce at least a reasonable solution. As usual, I invite you to post some code if you want a more detailed and specific answer.

First of all, check for tools which do what you asked. I know of [py-mon](https://pypi.org/project/py-mon/), which seems to be [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) for Python, but I never had the need to use it.

In case you don't like it, you can implement your subprocesses idea.

First, create an entry point for your script, ideally a function which does what you want to do when changes are detected.

Then make a `watchdog.py` (or however you want to call it) file where you start the function in a subprocess, then kill the subprocess and start a new one when you detect change in observed folders via watchdog.

To implement it, start from the example in the [watchdog pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) and put a sprinkle of [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in it.
Now, I don't know if it's feasible without a look at your code, but it seems at least a reasonable solution.

If you want to develop on this, post some code and we'll start from there, otherwise best of luck :-)

Comment: Well my question is: How can i restart the script using watchdog? If it is not possible using watchdog, how can I use subprocess?

Comment: I think I explained how you can do that. In short, you are going to have two files, `repeatable_script.py` and `watchdog.py`. The first does whatever you want to do on the files you are observing, the second launches `repeatable_script.py` on a subprocess, uses watchdog to check on the files and restarts the subprocess if watchdog finds changes. 
If you want implementation, please provide your code, something to start from.

Comment: But I don't need another file to run my main script in a subprocess: I am running a script with --reload option...

Comment: You can do it in a single script, but please post your code, otherwise I can't do much more than speculating.

Comment: Adjusted my question